# cairographics glade gtk3 c programming

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo, glade

I'm trying to develop an app using GTK3 + Glade and following examples and suggestions on internet I can obtain a first prototype of the application.
Now I want to add some plots in the app. I found that, in this contest, the Cairo library is the right solution. For the Cairo library I found this tutorial http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/

I tried to merge GTK3, Glade and Cairo using the C language but I'm not sure to use this tools in the right way.

Could you suggest me an example where using these tools is built an app that, e.g. pushing a button appear the plot of a curve?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Glade, you just need to add a GtkDrawingArea and you draw in it using cairo. Give a look at my [gtk3-graph](https://github.com/liberforce/gtk-samples/tree/master/c/gtk3-graph) sample application that uses GTK+ 3 and cairo to plot a curve.